# WP - not sending email

Tags: wp-mail

I have set up Wordpress locally and I am trying to send an email with this function:

```
$key = get_password_reset_key($user);
$url = 'http://frontend.web.node.net/reset-password?token=' . $key;
$to = $param['email'];
$subject = 'Passord reset';
$body = 'Du kan tilbakestille passordet ditt på denne lenken' . $url;
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if (!$sent) {
  return ['error' => 'email was not sent'];
}

return ['success' => 'mail has been sent'];
```

But, when I am trying to send an email like that, the email is never sent, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does WP send email on it's own?  (how is email setup?) - http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-not-sending-email-issue/

Comment: What mail server are you using? For this function to work, the settings SMTP and smtp_port (default: 25) need to be set in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_mail()` uses phpMailer which defaults to localhost so if your development server is not configured as a mail server, the email won't fly.

Use the 'wp_mail_failed' action hook to get the WP_Error that's thrown so you can further troubleshoot the problem.